# error in fromDer from forge.asn1 with certificate .p12 .pfx

Tags: javascript, asn.1, pfx, forge, p12

I have a problem.
I'm developing a program in which I can read .p12 and .pfx files.
My code is the following:

```
const pathSignFile = await uploadFile(signFile, ['p12', 'pfx'], '/signCerts');
const signBufferBinary = fs.readFileSync(pathSignFile, { encoding: 'binary' });
const data = isSignValidity(signBufferBinary, signPassword); 

return res.status(200).json({
        data
});
```

With some files I can access it, but in others the error lies here:

```
const asn1 = forge.asn1.fromDer(p12base64);
const p12 = forge.pkcs12.pkcs12FromAsn1(asn1, false, password);
return p12
```

The result I have is this:

```
{
    "byteCount": 3891,
    "remaining": 6
}
```

And status 500.

I tried:

```
const p12Der = forge.util.decode64(certOrPfx.toString('base64'));
const p12Asn1 = forge.asn1.fromDer(p12Der);
```

It didn't work.